# How can I make my "display: grid" responsive using media queries for mobile devices and tablets?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, css-grid

[Grid desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz7SG.png)
I want to make this grid desktop view responsive on mobile devices using media queries in my CSS. It's perfectly positioned in desktop but it's not responsive on mobile and tablets.

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
    gap: 25px;
}

/** Media Queries **/
@media screen and(max-width: 400px) {
    .grid-container {
        grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
    .grid-container .item-1 {
        grid-column: 1 / span 5;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
}
```

I created a grid with 5 columns for 5 different items (card). Then Item 1 spans the first three columns. Item 3 span from row 1 - 3 and Item 5 span from column 2 - 5.

```
.item-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    height: auto;
    background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
    position: relative;
}
.card-detail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
}

.item-3 {
    grid-column-start: 5;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

.item-5 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
```

I want the width of each grid item to span a width of 100% on mobile devices. On tablets I want the grid items to span 50% (that's 2 items in each row).

Comment: could you pls provide your HTML code

Answer (score -1):

Grid has the huge advantage of not requiring media queries to make the grid responsive. Using `auto-fit` or `auto-fill` in combination with `minmax` will adapt the number of columns depending on the screen on its own:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

/* for visualization only */
.grid > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
  <div>Box 4</div>
  <div>Box 5</div>
</div>
```

However, if you really want a strict 1-column mobile and 2-column desktop layout then you can go with media queries such as this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  
  .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 2),
  .grid > div:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
}

/* for visualization only */
.grid > div {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Box 1</div>
  <div>Box 2</div>
  <div>Box 3</div>
  <div>Box 4</div>
  <div>Box 5</div>
  <div>Box 6</div>
  <div>Box 7</div>
  <div>Box 8</div>
  <div>Box 9</div>
</div>
```

You should make use of the `nth-child()` selector in addition to using simply `grid-column: span 2`